# In vim, don't store {} motions in jumplist

Tags: vim

I find myself using vim's `{` and `}` motions frequently, to jump to the next/previous empty line. But those motions are captured in the jumplist, which makes the jumplist less useful because it's full of those motions instead of more "significant" jumps like going between files.

Is there a way to prevent `{` and `}` motions from being captured in the jumplist?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From `:help jumplist`:

> When the `:keepjumps` command modifier is used, jumps are not stored in the jumplist.

These mappings do what you want:

```
nnoremap } :<C-u>execute "keepjumps norm! " . v:count1 . "}"<CR>
nnoremap { :<C-u>execute "keepjumps norm! " . v:count1 . "{"<CR>
```

Comment: Thanks—you've solved a longstanding annoyance of mine. One followup, if I may: is there an easy way to silence the message that these mappings produce?

Comment: `nnoremap <silent> } …` should do.